Why is flex-wrap causing gaps in cross axis when set to wrap?
So I have been learning CSS as a beginner.  Recently I was exploring flex-box.  My original knowledge of flex-wrap: wrap; is that if overflow occurs along the main axis (flex-direction) it prevents it by wrapping the items in the next row (suppose flex-direction: row;).  What I don't seem to understand is that why it leaves gaps in the cross axis? Please see the code down below


#container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: azure;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#container div {
  height: 90px;
  width: 300px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
<h1>Flexbox Playground</h1>
<div id="container">
  <div style="background-color: #9400d3">violet</div>
  <div style="background-color: #4b0082">indigo</div>
  <div style="background-color: #0000ff">blue</div>
  <div style="background-color: #00ff00">green</div>
  <div style="background-color: #ffff00">yellow</div>
  <div style="background-color: #ff7f00">orange</div>
  <div style="background-color: #ff0000">red</div>
</div>



So since my initial item height was 100px, I did not see anything wrong in the cross axis. But then I tried to reduce the height of the item from 100px to 50px, I saw gaps in the cross axis (vertical direction). I wasn't expecting this and couldn't understand what was causing this behavior.  I am attaching pics for reference.  First one is when height of the item is 100px:  and second one is when the height has been reduced to 50px: 

This is because the default value of align-content is stretch to spread the divs across the height of the parent.
It needs to be set to start.


#container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: azure;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: start;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#container div {
  height: 90px;
  width: 25%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
<div id="container">
  <div style="background-color: #9400d3">violet</div>
  <div style="background-color: #4b0082">indigo</div>
  <div style="background-color: #0000ff">blue</div>
  <div style="background-color: #00ff00">green</div>
  <div style="background-color: #ffff00">yellow</div>
  <div style="background-color: #ff7f00">orange</div>
  <div style="background-color: #ff0000">red</div>
</div>




Thanks @Paulie_D. Your answer really helped . Seeing your answer , I have another question. I see you have used universal selector to apply some CSS properties. What exactly are you trying to achieve with the universal selector ?
